# Youtube 4K @60fps very high CPU on Lubuntu 64bit

Tags: youtube

My Desktop PC:- 
Asus P5KC
Intel Q6600 2.4GHz
4Gb RAM DDR3
Geforce GT1030
Lubuntu 64bit

Hi. I am using the right drivers from Linux
Lubuntu CPU is 80% to 100% on YT 4K video

on YouTube playing on 4K @60fps very high CPU
i tried h264ify still lag and very high CPU
tried different Internet browser, for example chrome, Firefox, Opera still lag and very high CPU.
tried patched chromium still lag very high CPU

i don't have this problem with windows 10 (64bit)
on windows 10 64bit CPU usage is 10% or 20% to 30% on YouTube 4K video 
all web browsers work excellent on windows 10, only problem is Memory (RAM) on windows 10

so that's why i tried Linux Lubuntu

any solution?

Comment: You should add to post - What browser, are you using using nvidia or nouveau drivers (am assuming desktop not laptop machine), how are you determining cpu use & is lagging from rendering (dropped frames) or from buffering issues?

Comment: can anyone help me?

Comment: Someone might. If you stop ranting and [edit] your question according to what was asked here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/991168/youtube-1080p-60fps-very-high-cpu-and-its-lagging-how-do-i-use-gpu#comment1598293_991168 PS - This is a Q&A site, not a forum. Comments are intended for clarification and request such as the aforementioned one, not for extended discussions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include which browser you are using, and to remove the rude pot shots. Nobody can help you when you don't provide enough details. Also, make sure hardware acceleration is enabled in the browser.

Comment: This is not directly related to Ubuntu...

Comment: hardware acceleration is switched on, still same problem.

Comment: this is related to LUbuntu 64bit

Comment: have you tried using 2K or 4K Youtube video's with 60fps?  what's your CPU usage ?

Comment: @UmbroKhan I've responded to your most recent comment with my answer below.

Comment: i included my web browser now could someone help me?

Answer (score -1):

## 60 Frames per second runs just fine

I must admit I didn't even know 60 FPS videos existed in Youtube before reading this question. So I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKM--8fzDpo) on Youtube which is very impressive.

Running the video and youtube statistics for nerds shows no dropped frames:

[image: Youtube 60fps.gif]

Conky which normally might show CPU load of 15-20% when running a regular video does rise a bit to 20-25% in comparison:

[image: Youtube conky 60fps.gif]

I just don't want people unduly concerned about Linux abilities to handle hardware acceleration.

This test was on Intel Skylake HD530 Graphics. I could duplicate test by rebooting to nVidia 970M graphics but not now.

Comment: Hi. Hello try with 4K video 60fps on Youtube then tell me CPU usage thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I've invested thousands of dollars in four 1080p screens and zero dollars in 2160p screens. Over next couple of years I'll make the reinvestment to 4k phone, monitors and finally 4k laptop. My laptop can drive 4K screen via HDMI or Thunderbolt3 I just don't have a 4K screen.

Comment: am using a desktop PC...so maybe that's why people have different results